# ImportError: No module named counselor.settings when using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

My crawler structure is as follows:

```
├── README.md
├── counselor
│   ├── filter_words.py
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── langconv.py
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── queue.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── spiders
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── wiki.py
│   └── zh_wiki.py
└── scrapy.cfg
```

My main.py is below:

```
from scrapy import cmdline
cmdline.execute('scrapy crawl wikipieda_spider'.split())
```

My counselor/spiders/wiki.py is below:

```
class WiKiSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    urlQueue = Queue()
    name = 'wikipieda_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['zh.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:%E8%AE%A1%E7%AE%97%E6%9C%BA%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B']
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'counselor.pipelines.WikiPipeline': 800}
    }
    ......
```

My counselor/settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'counselor'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['counselor.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'counselor.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'counselor.pipelines.WikiPipeline': 800,
}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
```

And in the project root directory, I have scrapy.cfg:

```
[settings]
default = counselor.settings

[deploy]
#url = http://localhost:6800/
project = counselor
```

Now I go to my project root (the same directory as scrapy.cfg) and execute:

```
python counselor/main.py 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py:14: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  from cryptography import utils, x509
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "counselor/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    cmdline.execute('scrapy crawl wikipieda_spider'.split())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 114, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 69, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 294, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named counselor.settings
```

My code doesn't directly imports counselor.settings. Why is it this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because scrapy DOES import it, based on the project name in your config.  All you need to do is turn your "counselor" folder into a module by adding a `__init__.py`.  It doesn't need any content; you can just add a line with `#` for convenience.